# Qt Creator with Visual C++ 11

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, qt-creator

I want to use Qt Creator with MS VC++ 11 but it says there is no toolchain to build Qt.
I installed Qt with the full SDK installer.
What to do now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't MSVC++ 11 comes with Visual Studio 11? If so then Qt hasn't supported `makespec` file for that version AFAIK (correct me if I am wrong). But following are the (rough) steps for running Qt Creator with `MSVC 2010 nmake/cl` tool-chain..

1. Download Qt SDK 4.8.2 compiled using `msvc-2010` toolchain from this [site](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads) (second page).
2. Install MS VC++ 2010 free development tools (or full SDK), which comprises of `nmake/cl/cdb` executables.
3. Restart PC so as to initialize environment variable and all.
4. Start `Qt Creator`, by now you will notice `msvc-2010` tool-chain has been identified by Qt Creator (Tools -> Options Dialog). If not then manually add it.
5. Also confirm that Qt version 4.8.2 of `msvc-2010` has been identified in `Qt Versions` tab. If not then manually add it by giving path of `qmake` in `bin` of Qt SDK folder. It will also select `msvc-2010` tool-chain automatically.
6. Here you go, now go to Projects and in Build Settings, select `msvc-2010` tool-chain and compile. Make sure `win32-msvc2010` is selected as `makespec` file.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

try building using the makespec of Visual Studio 2010.

`SET QMAKESPEC=win32-msvc2010`

before running configure and qmake should do the job