# First console application in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Why my first console application in Qt doesn't work?

I'm using version:

Qt Creator 2.7.0

Based on Qt 5.0.2 (32 bit)

windows 7

Code:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    qDebug()<<"hello world";
    
    return a.exec();
}
```

It gives me this output:

> 'cl' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
> program or batch file. jom:
>
> C:\210\build-hello-Desktop_Qt_5_0_2_MSVC2012_64bit-Debug\Makefile.Debug
> [debug\main.obj] Error 1 jom:
>
> C:\210\build-hello-Desktop_Qt_5_0_2_MSVC2012_64bit-Debug\Makefile
> [debug] Error 2 13:51:15: The process
>
> "C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited with code 2. Error
> while building/deploying project hello (kit: Desktop Qt 5.0.2 MSVC2012
> 64bit) When executing step 'Make'

Compilers settings:
[image]

Comment: Seems like something with your compiler. Check in QtDesigner settings if your toolsets and compilers are set properly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434064/qt-error-2-at-compile-time

Comment: @Blood Thanks for answer, but I don't know how to do it since I'm absolte beginner in Qt, I just donwloaded and installed it, I mean how can I see whether it is set properly or not?

Comment: @HalimQarroum Those errors seem very different to me

Comment: Are you sure `cl` and the binaries provided by Qt5.0.2 are in your `PATH` ?

Comment: @HalimQarroum I just installed it, so I suppose so, how can I check it?

Comment: open cmd.exe and type cl or better open VS command prompt and do the same

Comment: it shows copyrights and usage

Comment: is it what it should be there?

Comment: question has been updated

Comment: @feribaco post the solution as anwser

Answer (score 1):

Problem was that program didn't have access to folder where it was saved.

Comment: You can accept your own answer as it actually solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I installed the Microsoft Visual C++ IDE then Qt Creator. After that open Qt Creator, go to Tools -> Options menu, in the Build & Run option, select compilers tab Microsoft Visual C++ compiler must be detected, or you can add it and try to compile your program again. Your program seems correct.

Comment: I added screenshot to my main question above, is there anything wrong?

Comment: you have visual c++ 11, qt doesn't work properly with it. remove it and install the version 10, according to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950565/qt-creator-with-visual-c-11

Comment: Can I somehow use compiler from MS VS2012 that I have already installed ?

Comment: I am not sure, but why are you insist on not using vs2010. It worked for me great and definitely will work for you, too.

Comment: because this tutorial u sent me seems quite complicated and time-consuming to me. Or is it  just VS2010 what I need to install and that's it? Will it then automatically detect?

Comment: I mean for example, I don't have enough experience to see what's meant by the 3rd step "initialize environment variable and all."

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would recommend to do is to try compile your project within VS command prompt using quake/nmake clean/nmake to see if a toolchain (means VS) + QT installation working properly. Then next step to go on with QT Creator.

VS2012 works perfectly with Qt5 and it's much much much faster then VS2010

If you have VS installed somewhere in your Start->Applications->Microsoft VS->Tools ..etc (where a shortcut located) you should see Developer command prompt. So you run it, get command prompt, change working directory to where your project is located. Then you run quake, nmake clean, nmake commands. Your project should be build in command line.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I'm a beginner and don't rlly understand what are u talking about, could u describe in more detail what I should do?

Comment: well.. then probably you should first play a bit around visual studio creating basic console projects and read a bit about Makefiles, nmake...

Comment: Well, I just want to figure out why it is not working, I don't want to spend another hours by learning something absolutely different...

Comment: The code is correct, the compilers seem set up correctly since there isn't any error only warning, where else could be problem?